# Namespace error in shiny module with conditional panel

Tags: r, module, shiny

I programmed a little app where you see a radio button which you could use to switch between a plotly chart and a rendered table. It works. After that I read Shiny documentation on modules and ended up with this app:

my app.R

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           chartTableSwitchUI("firstUniqueID")
           )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  callModule(chartTableSwitch, "firstUniqueID")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and I coded a globar.R that looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

#define a simple dataframe for module example
X <- c("a", "b", "c")
Y <- c(1,2,3)
df <- data.frame(X,Y)

#UI function for first module
chartTableSwitchUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    radioButtons("rb1", "View", choices = c(ns("Chart"), ns("Table")), 
                 selected = "Chart", inline = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.rb1 == 'Chart'", ns=ns, 
    plotlyOutput(ns("chart"))),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.rb1 == 'Table'", ns=ns, 
    tableOutput(ns("chartTable")))
     )
    }

#Server logic for first module
    chartTableSwitch <- function(input, output, session){
    output$chart <- renderPlotly(
    plot_ly(df, x = ~X, y = ~Y) 
  )

  output$chartTable <- renderTable(df)
}
```

If I run the app the radio buttons are there but no plot or chart. Just the radio buttons.

Some research here on StackExchange gave me the hint that this is probably due to namespacing error but I do not know what exactly the problem is.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 6):

1) `ns` function should be called on `radioButtons` name ("rb1" in your case) and conditional checking should be adapted to that.

2) There is no need to call `ns` on you choice names.

Change your module UI function to:

```
#UI function for first module
chartTableSwitchUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    radioButtons(ns("rb1"), "View", choices = c("Chart", "Table"), 
                 selected = "Chart", inline = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = paste0('input[\'', ns('rb1'), "\'] == \'Chart\'"),
      plotlyOutput(ns("chart"))),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = paste0('input[\'', ns('rb1'), "\'] == \'Table\'"),
      tableOutput(ns("chartTable")))
  )
}
```

see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109671/r-shiny-modules-with-conditionalpanel-and-reactives) for explanation.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I read in documentation that one should not use the paste0 command. Instead on should use ns=ns in the conditional panel. Is this not true? If I use your UI functin the exactly same behavior appears. I see only the radio buttons.

Comment: have you reloaded all of your app code after changing `chartTableSwitchUI`? If not then `ui` contains reference to old code. I tested this on my computer and it works fine. As for alternative to using `paste` -- could you post a link? I haven't found any example how to do it like you suggest

Comment: Examples of using `ns = ns` instead of `paste0()`: [1](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/pull/1735#issuecomment-307249482),  [2](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-modules-and-conditionalpanel/2040). When I used `ns = ns`, I received the error `Warning: Error in FUN: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'`

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct but it needs a small change. Instead of using the `ns()` around the choices of radioButton, you should use it around the input id of the radioButton as follows:

```
 radioButtons(ns("rb1"), "View", choices = c("Chart", "Table"), 
             selected = "Chart", inline = TRUE)
```

and it should work now. See image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O6GD.png)