# Conditional Panel does not work after being modularized

Tags: r, shiny

I have a weird issue with conditionalPanel in shiny dashboard.
I modularized my chart UI components as I need to call it multiple times.

The conditional Panel seems to work fine if I call it only once. However, if I attempted to call more than once, it stopped working.

Below is the reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(highcharter)
library(lubridate)

chartUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    verbatimTextOutput(ns("group")),
    selectInput(ns("freq"),"Select frequency:",
                choices = list("Yearly" = "Y","Half yearly" = "H","Quarterly" = "Q",
                               "Monthly"="M"), selected = "Yearly", multiple = FALSE),
    dateInput(ns("dates"), "Select start date:",format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", value = dmy("1/1/2014")),
    selectInput(ns("link"),"Select link ratio:",choices = list("All" = "all", "Standard" = "std"),selected = "all"),
    conditionalPanel("input.link == 'std'", ns=ns, sliderInput(ns("std.month"),"No of months:",min=1,max=119,value=60))
  )  
} 
ui <- shinyUI(
  ui = dashboardPagePlus(skin = "red",
                         header = dashboardHeaderPlus(
                           title = "TITLE",
                           titleWidth = 700
                         ),
                         dashboardSidebar(),
                         body = dashboardBody(
                           # boxPlus(
                           #   width = NULL,title = "CHART",closable = TRUE,enable_sidebar = TRUE,
                           #   sidebar_width = 15,sidebar_start_open =  FALSE,sidebar_content = chartUI("chartui1"),
                           #   highchartOutput("")
                           # ),

                           boxPlus(
                             width = NULL,title = "CHART",closable = TRUE,enable_sidebar = TRUE,
                             sidebar_width = 15,sidebar_start_open =  FALSE,sidebar_content = chartUI("chartui2"),
                             highchartOutput("")
                           )
                         ),
                         title = "DashboardPage"
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I only call chartui2, conditional panel works fine. But if I call both chartui1 and chartui2, both of them no longer work.

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109671/r-shiny-modules-with-conditionalpanel-and-reactives. With modules, the input IDs are no longer `input.link` but a combination of the `id` value given when calling the module (e.g., `chartui1`) and the input id (e.g., `link`).

Comment: I did look at this post and I thought the issue with input IDs have been resolved by adding `ns=ns` in the code. Reference: [link](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1586). Or else it wouldnt work even if I just call the module once. However, it does work. It just stopped working if I call the module twice.

Comment: I see. Sorry for hastily marking it as a possible duplicate. I removed the flag. Have you tried to use `uiOutput + renderUI` instead of `conditionalPanel`?

Answer (score 1):

A minimal example with `uiOutput / renderUI` would be:

```
library(shiny)

dyn_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(selectInput(ns("show"), "show or not", choices = c("hide", "show")),
          uiOutput(ns("dyn")))
}

dyn_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$dyn <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    if (input$show == "show") {
      sliderInput(
        inputId = ns("std_month"),
        "No of months:",
        min = 1,
        max = 119,
        value = 60
      )
    }
  })
}

ui <- basicPage(dyn_ui("test"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(module = dyn_server, id = "test")
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

---

**Edit:**

In fact, a minimal example works well with `conditionalPanel` too (see below). So something else about your app is causing a conflict. Not sure what it is, but I would start adding components one by one and see when these minimal examples start misbehaving.

```
library(shiny)

dyn_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("show"), "show or not", choices = c("hide", "show")),
    conditionalPanel(
      ns = ns,
      condition = "input.show == 'show'",
      sliderInput(
        inputId = ns("std_month"),
        "No of months:",
        min = 1,
        max = 119,
        value = 60
      )
    )
}

ui <- basicPage(
  dyn_ui("test"),
  dyn_ui("test2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Actually, I think I have figured out how to solve the issue. I need to include the whole section `boxPlus` code into the my ui function. It works fine now. Thanks