# Using Conditional Panels in Shiny Modules

Tags: r, shiny, module

I am trying to use a conditional panel within a Shiny module. In the simplified example, I would like the numeric input box to show if the select box is equal to "Three". However, the numeric input box does not show even when the condition is true.  I know the problem is related to the namespace but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I've tried these solutions but neither worked:

[Namespace error in shiny module with conditional panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381720/namespace-error-in-shiny-module-with-conditional-panel)

[R Shiny modules with conditionalPanel and reactives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109671/r-shiny-modules-with-conditionalpanel-and-reactives)

My simplified code is:

```
Example_UI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    box(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput(NS(id, "SELECT_INPUT"), "Select:", c("One", "Two", "Three"))
        ),
        column(
          width = 6,
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input$SELECT_INPUT == 'Three'",
            numericInput(NS(id, "NUMERIC_INPUT"))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: See `?conditionalPanel`, you have to add the `ns` when there are modules.

Comment: To add some detail to @StéphaneLaurent's comment: Shiny "knows' you're using a module and can "adjust" widget IDs in many cases to ensure it modifies the correct widget in the way you want.  Javascript doesn't know you're using modules, so can't do this.  The `condition` parameter in `conditionalPanel` is a Javascript expression.  So you need to provide the namespace manually.

Comment: To see what Javascript thinks your widgets are called, Inspect the source code of the app's web page in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional Panel accepts argument NS for usage in modules.
See the `call namespace here!!` comment:

#### Full example:

```
library(shiny)

Example_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    shinydashboard::box(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput(ns("SELECT_INPUT"), "Select:", c("One", "Two", "Three"))
        ),
        column(
          width = 6,
          conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.SELECT_INPUT == 'Three'",
            numericInput(ns("NUMERIC_INPUT"),"Number",value = 1),
            ns=NS(id)  # call namespace here!!
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
}



ui <- fluidPage(
  Example_UI("one"),
  Example_UI("two")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works as expected.